# resize image using javascript creates blank canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, image-resizing

I am resizing the images using javascript and canvas, but some of the resized images are of a black background.

Below is the code:

```js
function resizeImage(input, maxWidth, maxHeight, callback) {
  var data;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
          var oc = document.createElement('canvas'), octx = oc.getContext('2d');
          oc.width = img.width;
          oc.height = img.height;
          octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          oc.width = maxWidth;
          oc.height = maxHeight;
          if (img.width > maxWidth) {
            octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
            octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
            data = oc.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
          } else {
            data = oc.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
          }
          callback(data);
        };
        img.src = event.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function run() {
    resizeImage(
      document.getElementById('image'), 
      600, 600, 
      function(dat) { 
    document.getElementById('preview').src= dat; 
      }
    )
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Resize</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Use this image to upload - <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ckNzNNR.jpg">https://i.imgur.com/ckNzNNR.jpg</a> to see the bug.</p>

  <input id="image" type="file" onchange="run()">
  <img id="preview" src="">
  
  <p><b>It creates blank image, works fine for some of the image </b></p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the live JS bin, if you want to test the live - https://jsbin.com/kivojewuti/edit?html,js,output

It works for some of the images but not for all images. One of the images where resize image doesn't work is linked in code.

Why does it fail for some of the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting `oc.width`/`oc.height` twice, with a draw instruction in between? (Changing the canvas dimensions will clear the canvas, so once you've sized it, you typically don't want to touch those dimensions *unless* you want to hard-clear the canvas)

Instead, load the image, and then in its onload handler you:

1. first check which dimensions to use (either img width/height or scaled down based on maxw/maxh), then
2. create your canvas, set its width/height, *then* get the 2d context. Then
3. use `ctx.drawImage(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height)`, which will now automatically effect resizing if necessary, and finally
4. get the (possibly resized) image as a data url.

Comment: I can (https://jsbin.com/femocomiku/edit?html,js,output), although that feels a bit like you asking me to do your work for you, since this should have already been enough information for you to update your code. At the very least, enough for you to try to update your code, with a comment going "I tried this but I couldn't get it to work" =)

Comment: You are right, I should have updated code with the error I have received while trying your approach earlier - Just if that matters, I tried and got something like this (https://i.imgur.com/yp2uQMJ.jpg) and I tried to dig more, yet could not find a glitch. Your above code is helpful, I will dig into it to solve my problem. Thank you so much for tremendous help on guiding the right way to do it. This help does matter a lot to help me find right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code below will do your trick. Keep in mind that this doesn't respect the original image ratio if it was too big. It will just squeeze it in the 600x600 box.

```
function resizeImage(input, maxWidth, maxHeight, callback) {
    var data;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                var oc = document.createElement('canvas'), octx = oc.getContext('2d');

                if (img.width > maxWidth || img.height > maxHeight) {
                    // Image is too big -> resize
                    oc.width = maxWidth;
                    oc.height = maxHeight;
                } else {
                    // Image will fit - use original sizes
                    oc.width = img.width;
                    oc.height = img.height;
                }

                octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
                data = oc.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);

                callback(data);
            };
            img.src = event.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```